# How to get current recipe attribute file to be loaded first?

Tags: chef-infra

I have recipes and attribute files for nodes. E.g. localhost and linode. I am trying to get the attribute file to load first (and to set hostname etc) before the default or other attributes. Example:

attributes/localhost.rb:

```
default[:hostname] = "localhost"
default[:nginx][:hostname] = 'mbdev-localhost'

include_attribute 'mbdev::common'
```

attributes/common.rb

```
default[:nginx][:website1][:url] = "subdomain." + default[:nginx][:hostname]
```

recipes/localhost.rb

```
include_recipe 'mbdev::default'
```

runlist:

```
'mbdev::localhost'
```

However it seems include_attribute makes the 'common' attribute to load first. And so nginx-hostname is not yet set...

The order I get is:
1) Loading attributes/default.rb
2) Loading attributes/common.rb
3) Error about the +

How can I get localhost.rb to load before common.rb?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, attribute files are loaded in alphabetical order. This used to be not fully consistent everywhere but was fixed in [CHEF-2903](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2903).

Thus, your `attributes/common.rb` is loaded before `attributes/localhost.rb` simply because it comes earlier alphabetically. An exception from the rule is `attributes/default.rb` which is always loaded before any other attributes files in a cookbook.

Generally, the load order of attribute files is the following:

1. load the attributes of all cookbook dependencies in alphabetical order
2. load `attributes/default.rb` (is it exists)
3. load any other attributes files in alphabetical order by filename

You can load an attribute file earlier than it would normally be loaded by using `include_attribute`, but you can't make it load later that way.

This logic is hardcoded in chef and can't be changed. You can perform a few work-around though:

- You could write your attribute files in a way that load order is not important anymore
- You could name recipes/attributes in a way consistent with the above logic
- You can enforce that an attribute file is loaded again:

  ```
  node.from_file(run_context.resolve_attribute("cookcook_name", "attribute_file"))
  ```

Comment: You just solved my brain block about how the damn recipe knows about the attributes file!!!!! +10 if I could... ty

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `override_attribute`? That's why they exist :-) See [Attribute Precedence](http://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence).

Comment: That will require me to have all host related attributes repeat themselves on every host.

Comment: Then define a role for it